# URL Routing to Default Page

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I have an asp.net 4.0 web forms app setup with url rereouting.  In development, my app's URL looks perfect.  I have a page called enrollnow.aspx that responds to the routing, so if I type in localhost/enrollnow/abc, my app responds as expected.

Once promoted into my staging environment however, the URL is off.  I have a domain, and a virtual dir created off of my domain called "enrollnow".  So basically, my URL outside of development is: mydomain.com/**enrollnow**/*enrollnow*/abc - where the first enrollnow is the directory, the second enrollnow is the page name, and the abc is my route value.

Is there any way I can have the "default page" respond, so the second enrollnow (which is enrollnow.asp) isnt required?  Perhaps I can rename my enrollnow.aspx page to default.aspx, or I can change the mapping in my routetable?  Heres my routetable, incase that helps.  thanks!

Routetable:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("PURLRoute", New Route("EnrollNow/{PURL_ID}", New PageRouteHandler("~/EnrollNow.aspx")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to omit "EnrollNow/" in your route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("PURLRoute", new Route("{PURL_ID}",
    new PageRouteHandler("~/EnrollNow.aspx")))
```

BUT: The problem will be for the routing table to distinguish between a parameter value and a route to another page. For instance, say, you have another route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("AnotherRoute", new Route("AnotherPage",
    new PageRouteHandler("~/AnotherPage.aspx")))
```

Then the behaviour when specifying the URL `mydomain.com/enrollnow/AnotherPage` will depend on the order you added the two routes above. If "PURLRoute" is added **before** "AnotherRoute" the URL will be routed to "EnrollNow.aspx" and "AnotherPage" will be interpreted as a parameter value for {PURL_ID} (which you probably don't want). If "PURLRoute" is added **after** "AnotherRoute" you will be routed to "AnotherPage.aspx" (which is good, I think) but then you can never specify "AnotherPage" as a value for {PURL_ID}.

Comment: Thanks so much Slauma, you hit the nail on the head with this one.  The routing works as expected now.  Fortunately for me, we only intend for this application in particular to route to the default page only, so the "another page" scenario shouldnt affect us too much, but i do appreciate the time.  Thanks!